# Supervision.decider strategy in akka 2.6.0

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-supervision

I have to pass `supervision.decider` but in akka 2.6.0+ `Materializer` does not have similar settings.

Can anyone share how to write below code in higher version:

```scala
val mat: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer(Actor Materializersettings(supervision.decider))
```

Tried new way, not picking as strategy class requires `String`:

1.

```scala
val mat: Materializer = Matrializer(actorsystem)
mat.system.settings.supervisionstratgyclass = ???
```

2. `ActorAttributes(supervision.decider)`

Any idea would be appreciated how to pass supervision strategy through materializer.

How we pass custom supervision strategy in settings? I don't use streams. It will simple startup call with materializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to setup a supervision strategy for a stream. Here you have some examples of how to do it from the official documentation: [Stream error - supervision strategies](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-error.html#supervision-strategies).

As you can see, in the following example a default supervision strategy is being set for the runnable graph

```
val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
  case _: ArithmeticException => Supervision.Resume
  case _                      => Supervision.Stop
}
val source = Source(0 to 5).map(100 / _)
val runnableGraph =
  source.toMat(Sink.fold(0)(_ + _))(Keep.right)

val withCustomSupervision = runnableGraph.withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
```

In this other one, a supervision strategy is being defined at `Flow` level

```
val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
  case _: ArithmeticException => Supervision.Resume
  case _                      => Supervision.Stop
}
val flow = Flow[Int]
  .filter(100 / _ < 50)
  .map(elem => 100 / (5 - elem))
  .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
val source = Source(0 to 5).via(flow)
```

Comment: Thanks for input. I am not using any streams. It's simple startup and want to system exit as custom decider startegy on exception. Looking to implement with new materializer changes.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Based on the tags of the post, I thought you were working with akka-streams. In this case you would need to use `Behaviors.supervise(behavior).onFailure(supervisorStrategy)`. That helper will let you supervise an actor (`Behavior`) and then call the method `onFailure` to decide which supervision strategy you want to apply based on your needs. The official docs [Akka - fault tolerance](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/fault-tolerance.html) have good examples about how to do it